# Optimize validation for a ModelChoiceField inside a formset Django?

Tags: django, validation, formset

The first thing Django's inline formset does when you submit data is trigger validation for each of its forms in a loop:

```
for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
     form = self.forms[i]
     self._errors.append(form.errors)
```

In a picture where the formset is a table with rows for the individual forms, validation works row-by-row. If there's a `ModelChoiceField` in the form, the value selected in each row will be looked up in the `ModelChoiceField`'s queryset, resulting in at least one additional db hit per row.

```
key = self.to_field_name or 'pk'
value = self.queryset.get(**{key: value})
```

Now if all these querysets are the same (as mine are), this seems like a a waste. The queryset doesn't change from row to row, is there any way to cache it?

More generally, would it be a more efficient to do validation in columns, as it were, e.g. by first collecting the fields from the form's class, and doing a loop through all the forms (rows) per each field (column)?

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid that querysets by replacing `ModelChoiceField` with normal `ChoiceField` feeded by choices populated earlier in code, for example:

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
    your_foreign_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=list(YourForeignModel.objects.values_list('id', 'display_name')))
```

That way, queryset will be executed once, when class (not class object) is created. But this leads to some troubles - list of foreign objects will be populated when application starts (or when this code is reached at first time). To avoid that, you can move your choices to `__init__`

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('your_foreign_choices')
        super(YourModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['your_foreign_field'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

That way all you need to do is pass populated choices to your formset (so it will be passed further, into each form):

```
YourModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(YourModelForm)

def your_view(request):
    formset =  YourModelFormSet(form_kwargs={'your_foreign_choices': list(YourForeignModel.objects.values_list('id', 'display_name'))})
```

Comment: But then you lose all the model niceness, like out-of-the-box validation, saving etc...

Comment: Saving is done properly, validation too - unless your choices are generated wrong, but you can also use here `ModelChoiceField`, it should work fine. Using `ModelChoiceField` with choices will prevent execution of queryset, field will use pre-populated choices instead.

Comment: For reference, in Django > 2 you cannot pass choices to a `ModelChoiceField`